# Excel - Accessing Multiple Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

Since I am doing some checking on multiple ranges in the event"

```
Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
```

ןf the user modifies multiple ranges in the sheet, the `Target` will contain multiple ranges in the format like "A2:A4,D2:D4,H2:H4".

As I need to check each range independently (e.g. the first row of each range), is there anyway to loop through each range?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx

Comment: There should be multiple Areas; so check the first row of each area.

Comment: So they are called "Areas", thank you for the information guys!